# ActiveRecord changing the name of an assocation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building database with ActiveRecord that has a Users table, a Recipes table, and a RecipeSaves table (the latter being a join table for the first two). When I try to use the Rails console to see a particular user's recipe_saves, I get this message:

`Rails couldn't find a valid model for RecipeSafe association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass. (NameError)`

I have searched the whole app, and the word "safe" never appears anywhere, so I have no idea where the "RecipeSafe" is coming from. In case I made a typo earlier, I made sure to re-save all files, and I dropped and recreated the database, as well.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say that you have a `RecipeSaves` table, do you mean that you have a `recipe_saves` table and a `RecipeSaves` model? What does the association look like?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is what I meant. My User model currently looks like this:
```has_many :recipe_saves, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :saved_recipes, through: :recipe_saves
    has_many :recipes```
The `has_many :recipes` is because Users can create a recipe (which makes the user_id part of the Recipe), but also can save other people's recipes. Hence the two associations. ActiveRecord recognizes `user.recipes`, but `user.saved_recipes` is what brings up the error message from the OP.

Comment: @LeavingValhalla Can you please share your model files too?

Answer (score 2):

```rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class RecipeSave < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :recipe_saves, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :saved_recipes,
    through: :recipe_saves,
    source: :recipe        # NOTE: use `recipe` association in `RecipeSave` model
                           #       instead of `saved_recipes`
end

# >> User.first.saved_recipes
# Rails couldn't find a valid model for RecipeSafe association.
```

We can take a look at how rails sees `has_many :recipe_saves` association:

```
>> User.reflect_on_association(:recipe_saves)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x00007f728a1c4a90
 @active_record=User(id: integer, name: string),

 @class_name="RecipeSafe", # NOTE: rails expects this class to be defined 

 @inverse_name=nil,
 @klass=nil,
 @name=:recipe_saves,
 @options={},
 @plural_name="recipe_saves",
 @scope=nil>
```

`RecipeSafe` class name is [inferred](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L677) from `:recipe_saves`:

```
>> :recipe_saves.to_s.singularize.camelize
=> "RecipeSafe"

# NOTE: this inflection is incorrect
>> :recipe_saves.to_s.singularize
=> "recipe_safe"

>> ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections
...
@singulars=
...
  [/([^f])ves$/i, "\\1fe"],  # <= this one did it.
...

>> :recipe_saves.to_s.sub(/([^f])ves$/i, "\\1fe")
=> "recipe_safe"
```

To fix it, add a new inflection rule:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.singular "saves", "save"
end
```

```
>> User.reflect_on_association(:recipe_saves).class_name
=> "RecipeSave"

>> User.first.recipe_saves
=> [#<RecipeSave:0x00007f44a8fa5048 id: 1, user_id: 1, recipe_id: 1>]

>> User.first.saved_recipes
=> [#<Recipe:0x00007f44ac2c3f38 id: 1, user_id: 1>]
```

---

To avoid messing with inflections, rename `RecipeSave` and `recipe_saves` table:

```rb
# in migration

create_table :recipe_bookmarks do |t|
  t.references :user,   null: false, foreign_key: true
  t.references :recipe, null: false, foreign_key: true
end
```

```rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class RecipeBookmark < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recipe_bookmarks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :bookmarked_recipes, through: :recipe_bookmarks, source: :recipe
end

# >> User.first.bookmarked_recipes
```

---

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association*

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html*

Comment: This is incredible, thank you so much for such a detailed and thorough response.